# How to handle ftp timeout issue in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

chunk is list container containts small list of files there may be 1000+ files but some of the files are not uploading and gives connection time out error is there any way to overcome this issue? on python3 ftplib

```
def uploader(self,chunk):
        print("ON ULOADER",chunk)
        print("Uplaoder", self.outer)
        pnglist = []
        csvlist = []


        print("Changed")
        try:
            dir = '/home/ubuntu/rabit'
            self.outer = dir + self.outputdir

            os.chdir(self.outer)
        except Exception as e:
            print("das", self.outer)
            print("exception", e)

        ftp = ftplib.FTP(self.host)
        ftp.login(self.username, self.password)
        print("OUTER", self.outputdir)
        ftp.cwd(self.outputdir)
        for file1 in chunk:
            #print("Name",file1)
            try:
                print("Name", file1)

                ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + file1, open(file1, 'rb'))
                #os.remove(file1)
                print(file1,"REMOVED")

            except Exception as  e:
                ftp.quit()
                ftp.close()
                print("DIRERROR",e)
                SingletonDecorator(
                    "UPDATE gdl_input_files  SET processed ='4' , errordata='1' WHERE filename='" + file1 + "'",
                    function="insertion")

        ftp.quit()
        ftp.close()
        return 0
```

Comment: Have you considered `ftplib.FTP(self.host, timeout = `a bigger number`)`. You might also try multiple attempts at each file.

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't works i have given 50000